# Regular expression for specific number of symbols

Tags: javascript, regex

How to build pattern of regexp that allow "any 10" or "any 12" symbols? 
I tried this, but if number of symbols>10 it dont work.

> (^.{10})|(^.{12}$)

Comment: why need regex? try `yourstring.length` ...

Comment: Is a newline a legal character?

Comment: @helle: That depends on what the OP meant by *symbols*. I wouldn't expect it to include a newline.

Comment: @Phrogz: newline is certainly a legal character, we would be lost without it! Whether it is what the OP meant by a *symbol* or not is another matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say that is "ten characters, and optionally two more":

```
/^.{10}(?:..)?$/
```

Answer (score 3):

You should try this regex:

```
/^.{10}(?:..)?$/
```

It anchors to the start of the string, matches any 10 characters, then optionally matches two more, then anchors to the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

If I couldn't use `str.length` (e.g. I needed to pass a regex to a validation function) I would use:

```
/^[\d\D]{10}(?:[\d\D])?$/
```

in order to also allow newline characters, and hope that I never got a string with `\r\n` such that I would have to decide if that was really one character instead of two.

Comment: I had no idea JavaScript had no `//s` modifier. How awful.

Comment: Also surprising, in Ruby [`//m` is used](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/doc/re.rdoc) for getting `.` to include newlines.

Comment: Bizarre, and Ruby apparently has no option for making `/^$/` match within a string - normally `//m`!